# Can we create snowflake stored procedure using if and else statements

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can anyone give snowflake stored procedure for this table:

```
CREATE TABLE GANESH_T 
(
    IN_EMPLOYEEID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    IN_FIRSTNAME STRING,
    IN_LASTNAME STRING,
    IN_DEPARTMENT STRING,
    IN_POSITION STRING,
    IN_SALARY DECIMAL(10, 2)
);

INSERT INTO ganesh_T (in_EmployeeID, in_FirstName, in_LastName, in_Department, in_Position, in_Salary)
VALUES
    (1, 'John', 'Doe', 'Sales', 'Sales Manager', 55000.00),
    (2, 'Jane', 'Smith', 'HR', 'HR Specialist', 48000.50),
    (3, 'Bob', 'Johnson', 'IT', 'Software Engineer', 65000.75),
    (4, 'Alice', 'Williams', 'Finance', 'Financial Analyst', 60000.25),
    (5, 'Sarah', 'Davis', 'Marketing', 'Marketing Coordinator', 42000.75),
    (6, 'Michael', 'Lee', 'IT', 'Database Administrator', 70000.00),
    (7, 'Emily', 'Brown', 'Finance', 'Finance Manager', 75000.00),
    (8, 'David', 'Wilson', 'Sales', 'Sales Representative', 50000.50);
```

I need with if statements use SQL language only

I tried to create a snowflake stored procedure using if and else statements for specific database and use language SQL only.

Can anyone give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Check the examples in the link below

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE example_if(flag INTEGER)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
BEGIN
IF (FLAG = 1) THEN
    RETURN 'one';
ELSEIF (FLAG = 2) THEN
    RETURN 'two';
ELSE
    RETURN 'Unexpected input.';
END IF;
END;
$$
;
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/snowflake-scripting/if#examples